Lex not transferring to Q
In amazon connect, IVR reaching till Lex. But after that is should reach to matched intent Q but its keep saying in loop closing statement of BOT.
Timeout/default Q is working fine but for other Q its not transferring to respective Q.
Kindly suggest.
